# Cocoa: access @public NSArray after update it from one class to another

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, osx-lion

How can I access `@public NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` after updating it? From one class to another?

I can access it with calling `-(id)init`.. when program starts, but if I want to update it later, I get nil. What's the problem?

Simple example code:

MyFirstClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyFirstClass : NSObject
{
@public

    NSArray *testArray;

}

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender;

@end
```

MyFirstClass.m

```
#import "MyFirstClass.h"

@implementation MyFirstClass
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {

    //I can take this Array from here

    //testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"first", @"second", @"third", nil];

}
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

    //How take this Array?

    testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"first", @"second", @"third", nil];

}

@end
```

SimpleClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyFirstClass.h"

@interface SimpleClass : NSObject
{
    MyFirstClass *other;
}

-(IBAction)ButtonGet:(id)sender;

@end
```

SimpleClass.m

```
#import "SimpleClass.h"
#import "MyFirstClass.h"

@implementation SimpleClass

-(IBAction)ButtonGet:(id)sender {

    other = [[MyFirstClass alloc] init];     

    if(other->testArray) {
        NSLog(@"Working!");
    }
    else { NSLog(@"Not working!"); }

}

@end
```

Created example has two buttons in *.xib. One button named "Button" (MyFirstClass) and other "ButtonGet" (SimpleClass). So when program starts need to push "Button" and then "ButtonGet", after that NSLog should write "Working!" if it gets testArray and if not - "Not working!". It always shows "Not Working!".

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code where you declare the instance variable, where you assign it an array instance, and where you try to use it. Also, are you using garbage collection, ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: Thanks for Your comment, I'm not using garbage collection, I'm using manual memory management.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `awakeFromNib`, and from there right-click `testArray` in the debugger panel and select "Watch Variable". This way, the next times your variable is modified, the debugger will pause your program.

Comment: @zneak sorry I made a mistake, it's not wotking with awakeFromNib.. It's only wotks with - (id)init {...}. Maybe You know why? maybe something wrong with returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Objective C! If you feel overwhelmed, and would like to read some introductory material, please have a look at the links in Peter Hosey's excellent ["Useful Cocoa/Cocoa Touch Links" card](http://boredzo.org/cocoa-links-card/).

You create the `MyFirstClass` instance in `-[SimpleClass ButtonGet:]`, and since its `testArray` member isn't explicitly assigned to in `-[MyFirstClass init]`, it is (correctly) initialized to nil.  It will remain that way forever unless you assign something else to it, but you never do. (You only assign to it in `[MyFirstClass Button:]`, but you never call that method.)

Other things to consider:

- Manual memory management requires that you know the [Cocoa memory management rules](http://boredzo.org/cocoa-links-card/) and constantly keep them in mind while writing your code. For example, you need to retain the result of `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` when you assign it to a member variable, and release it in `-[MyFirstClass dealloc]`. Similarly, you need to release the `other` object in `-[SimpleClass dealloc]`.
- It is much cleaner to use properties (declared using `@property`) instead of directly referring to another class's member variables.
- Please consider following the [Cocoa Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and starting your method names with a lowercase letter. It makes your code fit better with the system APIs, and makes it much easier to read for other people.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answer. What do You mean saying "assign something else to it" can You give me example how to do that? I call it when press button, no?

Comment: You assign something to a member variable with the assign operator (`=`) -- you already wrote code do this in `-[MyFirstClass Button:]`. That code is never actually executed in your example, though. To call the method, you can (for example) insert the statement `[other Button:nil];` in `-[SimpleClass ButtonGet]` after you create the `MyFirstClass` object, but before you check `testArray`. Is there a button? You didn't mention any buttons in your question.

Comment: There are two buttons -(IBAction)Button: and -(IBAction)ButtonGet:, sorry I didn't mention that. So I execute this code when press "Button" button, no? And from other class other Button "ButtonGet"

Comment: My example scenario: Created example app has two buttons in *.xib. One button named "Button" (MyFirstClass) and other "ButtonGet" (SimpleClass). So when program starts need to push "Button" and then "ButtonGet", after that NSLog should write "Working!" if it gets testArray and if not - "Not working!". It always shows "Not Working!".

Comment: Put a breakpoint or an NSLog in `-[MyFirstClass Button:]` to verify that it actually runs -- it is probably not connected correctly in the xib. You also have to fix the unretained member issue, or else `testArray` will get deallocated almost immediately, and you'll have a pointer pointing nowhere.

Comment: It actually runs when pressed button, I was testing that everything before posting the code..

Comment: OK, the problem is that you create instances of `MyFirstClass` and `SimpleClass` in the xib, and connect the buttons to these instances, but `-[SimpleClass ButtonGet:]` creates a new instance of `MyFirstClass`, and checks `testArray` there instead of the instance from xib. I suggest you create an outlet for a `MyFirstClass` instance in `SimpleClass`, and connect the xib instance to it.

Comment: Thank You very much for You help Fnord, I fixed that finally!!! I was stuck on this for such a long time.. If I could vote you up 1000 times I would!!! Thank You!